# JQuery: предзагрузка изображений

Tags: jquery, javascript

Погуглил: все сводится к банальному циклу for и $.attr()

Упростил:

```
Файлы: 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png ... 10.png (по 250кб скажем каждый)

for(var i = 1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        now = file_dir + i + '.png';
        $('<img>').attr('src', now);
    }
```

Так вот по ощущениям что вешается браузер (мб. когда коннект слабый, или скажем какое-то изображение временно недоступно по тем или иным причинам). Можно ли как-то оптимизировать это, более "пассивно"? (в фоне грузить, продолжать выполнять другие $.on(); и скажем если не доступен в течении 10 секунд то перейти к следующему) может ещё кто что посоветует. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так навешивание таймеров, ожидающих загрузки никак не облегчит работу браузеру.
может вашему циклу, обертки какой-то не хватает? поэтому вешается браузер.
Всё равно jQuery юзаете, попробуйте через `.each()`:

```
$.fn.preloadImage = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
};

// и так:
var arr = [1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png ... 10.png];
$(arr).preloadImage();
```

Comment: Очень логично, спасибо! Может кто ещё что подскажет...